# How to submit a form element inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to submit a form inside a div on click of an external button outside the div and form.

I know the div tag class name. I don't the form name, class or id. It is randomly generated and I want to keep it that way.

There is only form at persent on the page but there can be more.

However There would be only one form inside the mentioned div tag

Comment: Is their only one form ?

Comment: `$('form').submit();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**.submit();**](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
 $("#YourExternalButtonId").on('click',function(){
      $(".YourDivClass").find("form").submit();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

this is option using jQuery

with clicking on submit button in form

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('div.classname form input[type="submit"]').click();
});
```

or submitting form

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('div.classname form').submit();
});
```